# How to split the string into intervals

Tags: java, split

The input is like the below

```
(3,7),(4,8),(1,2),(9,16),(13,18),(22,28)
```

How can we divide this into intervals like

```
(3,7)
(4,8)
(1,2)
(9,16)
(13,18)
(22,28)
```

Comment: How would you try to do it?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've tried `split`, but had problems because the comma is used within the parenthesis as well. A quick workaround is to change the delimiter that you're splitting on between those brackets, since that's easy enough, and then split in it:

```
String input = "(3,7),(4,8),(1,2),(9,16),(13,18),(22,28)";
input = input.replace("),(", ")@(");
String[] split = input.split("@");
```

(You can also use regex, but it might be a bit more difficult to understand how it works.)

Comment: Thanks mk. Can you help on how can we sort this string array

Comment: @user3371172 here's one I found by searching 'sort string array': `Arrays.sort(split);`

Answer (score 0):

The `String` class has a few nice functions for this purpose. For example:

1. Using `split(String regex)` with `regex = "\),\("`. Returns a `String[]`
2. Using `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` with `regex = "\),\("` and `replacement = "\)\\n\("`

Regular expressions are extremely powerful and any programmer should know the basics about them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
String result = input.replaceAll(")," , ")\n");

System.out.println(result);
```

Should give the result you wrote.